# Hitting fragment from push notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification

I am building an app that has an option when user click on push notifcation, he goes to the fragment on MainActivity(which is called Fragment1). Here is my entire code and i don't know how to write code for switching to the Fragment1. Could someone help me?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme2);
    btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dugme3);
    dugme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("developeri");
            Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to developeri topic");
        }
    });


    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

    StartFragment startFragment=new StartFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.myFragment, startFragment);
    ft.commit();
    btn1.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
   Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1")){
        //code for switching fragments



    }

}
 Button.OnClickListener  btnOnClickListener= new Button.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Fragment newFragment;
         if (view==btn1){
             newFragment =new Fragment1();

         }else if(view==btn2){
              newFragment =new Fragment2();
         }else if (view==btn3){
             newFragment =new Fragment3();
         }else{
             newFragment=new StartFragment();
         }
         FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, newFragment);
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
         transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
         transaction.commit();


     }
 };
```

EDIT: This "myFragment" is the first fragment that is on MainActivity and Fragment1 is the fragment to which i want to go when click on notification

EDIT1: This is activity_main XML file.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.dev3.fragmenti.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dugme1"
        android:text="Fragment1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dugme2"
        android:text="Fragment2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dugme3"
        android:text="Fragment3"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subscribe"
        android:text="Subscribe"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:id="@+id/myFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


</LinearLayout>
```

My logcat error:

```
06-06 13:37:21.498 16764-16764/com.example.dev3.fragmenti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dev3.fragmenti/com.example.dev3.fragmenti.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at com.example.dev3.fragmenti.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show us where you have these `myFragment` as well as `Fragment1` - are these on the same `activity_main` Layout XML file?

Comment: Yes, they are both on activity_main XML file. I cant display that XML file here because is too long. On MainActivity on the right side is myFragment and on the left side are 3 buttons for going on fragments(Button1 for going on Fragment1, Button2 for Fragment2, Button3 for Fragment3). I hope that i've cleared to you now.

Comment: OK, and you only want to add the Fragment1 (if action is gotoFragment1) - in that case, you simply add like : `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.Fragment1, new WhatEverYouNamedFragment1());` - by the way, replace `WhatEverYouNamedFragment1` with the name of your `Fragment` class which you want to load for `Fragment1`.

Comment: Well, that is the part that I don't understand. The name off the class where I want to go is Fragment1.(Fragment1 is really the name of the Fragment where I want to go from MainActivity). And then, why I should write (R.id.Fragment1, new WhatEverYouNamedFragment1()) when i want to go on Fragment1 not from Fragment1 to another fragment?

Comment: Please just paste your `activity_main` Layout file. Maybe you are confusing the issue - if you say you have declared both Fragments in your `activity_main` Layout file, then there is really no "fragment to go to" - you simply add/replace these Fragments by their ID `(R.id.*)`.

Comment: Okey, I will post but how, that file is too long to post in this section?

Comment: You can edit your question and include your activity_main XML.

Comment: I have posted mu XML file.

Comment: I have bad copied my XML. It has one more line above the whole code(that line is <LineraLayout) ,and at the end of the code that i copied linear Layout is closed, if you understand me.

Comment: I see, but you also only have `myFragment` as name of a `LinearLayout` - so this is the fragment place holder that you want to replace? By the way, is your code running successfully as it is or are you getting errors?

Comment: Well, until now it run successfull but now it throws me null pointer exception and logcat sends me to the part if (extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1")) in MyActivity

Comment: So, what should I write in part fragmentTransaction.replace(?)?

Comment: OK, please paste the error log. The null pointer problem can be sorted out - and then we look at the `Fragment` problem.

Comment: Change `if (extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1"))` to this: `if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("action") && extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1"))` - this way, it should not cause `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thats it! No more null pointer, thanks man. But, what I must write to switch to the Fragment1?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of the NullPointerException, you should Change

```
if (extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1"))
```

to this:

`if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("action") && extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1"))`

That way, it should not cause `NullPointerException` if the `extras` is `null` or does not contain key "`action`". So your code should look like this:

```
...
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();    
if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("action") &&   extras.getString("action").contains("goToFragment1")){
    //code for switching fragments 
    //try this 
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myFragment,new Fragment1()).commit();
}
```

By the way, I am not sure why you have myFragment as a `LinearLayout` - this should be a `FrameLayout` instead. In any case, please give this a try and let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: Its the same thing. It sends me to the first page, not on Fragment1(no errors in logcat)

Comment: But are you getting inside the `if` statement at all? Please write a log statement just to indicate if you are getting inside the `if` block.

Comment: It doesnt come to if. I dont have nothing from Log in logcat. And i now discovered that notifications from Firebase console dont want to come when app is in the foreground, butt this morning i could do that. I dont know is that helpful to you

Comment: In this case, please post a separate question for the Firebase+Notification issue so the community members can also help out. If the notification does not come through, we won't be able to test the functionality that you are looking for. By the way, you can edit this question and paste the link to the "related question".

Comment: I logged Bundle extras and again I have null pointer, that means that I don't have extras...